# org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in com.sforce.soap.partner.fault.UnexpectedErrorFault - upgradeURL

Tags: soap-api, java

I am using salesforce SOAP API version 8. This is Login code which i am using for login for Salesforce Soap API.

```
public String login(String userid, String passwd) {
    SoapBindingStub binding;
    un = userid;
    if (un.trim().length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    pw = passwd;
    if (pw.trim().length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    // Provide feed back while we create the web service binding
    //System.out.println(new Date()+" Creating the binding to the web service...");

    try {
        binding = (SoapBindingStub)new SforceServiceLocator().getSoap();

        binding._setProperty(SoapBindingStub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/8.0");

    } catch (ServiceException ex) {
        System.out.println(new Date()+" ERROR: creating binding to soap service, error was: "+ ex.getMessage());
        WebServerLogger.getLogger().log(new LogEntry("SFClient","login",
                "Could not connect to SalesForce, some configuration problem! \n Exception Text ::" + ex.getMessage()));
        return null;
    }

    // set the session header for subsequent call authentication
    binding._setProperty(SoapBindingStub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, binding._getProperty(SoapBindingStub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY));

    //For login of Professional account holders
    String clientID = "ABC/ABC/";
    CallOptions co = new CallOptions();
    co.setClient(clientID);

    // bind it to the current soap session
    binding.setHeader("SforceService", "CallOptions", co);

    // Time out after 2 minute
    binding.setTimeout(120000);
    //Saving current session time
    sessionTime =  System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Attempt the login giving the user feedback
    System.out.println(new Date()+"GOING TO LOGIN AT SALESFORCE .... SFUserId :: "+userid);
    try {
        loginResult = binding.login(un, pw);
    } catch (LoginFault lf) {
        System.out.println(lf.getExceptionMessage());
        WebServerLogger.getLogger().log(new LogEntry("SFClient", "sfLogin",
                "Could not login to SalesForce ["+userid+"] \nLoginFault:: "+lf));
        return null;
    } catch (UnexpectedErrorFault uef) {
        System.out.println(uef.getExceptionMessage());
        uef.printStackTrace();
        WebServerLogger.getLogger().log(new LogEntry("SFClient", "sfLogin",
                "Unexpected error while logging in to salesforce ["+userid+"] \n Unexcepted Fault:: " + uef));
        this.setSynchError(uef.getFaultString());
        return null;
    } catch (RemoteException re) {
        System.out.println(re.getMessage());
        re.printStackTrace();
        WebServerLogger.getLogger().log(new LogEntry("SFClient","sfLogin",
                "Remote exception while logging in to salesforce ["+userid+"] \n Remote Exception::" + re));
        this.setSynchError(re.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    //System.out.println(new Date()+" The session id is: " + loginResult.getSessionId());

    // set the session header for subsequent call authentication
    binding._setProperty(SoapBindingStub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,loginResult.getServerUrl());


    // Create a new session header object and set the session id to that
    // returned by the login
    SessionHeader sh = new SessionHeader();
    sh.setSessionId(loginResult.getSessionId());
    binding.setHeader(new SforceServiceLocator().getServiceName().getNamespaceURI(), "SessionHeader", sh);

    loggedIn = true;

    sessions.put(un, loginResult.getSessionId());

    return loginResult.getSessionId();

}
```

**loginResult = binding.login(un, pw);** At this line i am getting this exception. But when i restart Tomcat its start working fine. I am Using tomcat 6.

```
; nested exception is:
Dec 17 02:26:22 localhost catalina.sh[9228]: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in com.sforce.soap.partner.fault.UnexpectedErrorFault - upgradeURL
Dec 17 02:26:22 localhost catalina.sh[9228]: AxisFault
Dec 17 02:26:22 localhost catalina.sh[9228]: faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
Dec 17 02:26:22 localhost catalina.sh[9228]: faultSubcode:
Dec 17 02:26:22 localhost catalina.sh[9228]: faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in com.sforce.soap.partner.fault.UnexpectedErrorFault - upgradeURL
Dec 17 02:26:22 localhost catalina.sh[9228]: faultActor:
Dec 17 02:26:22 localhost catalina.sh[9228]: faultNode:
Dec 17 02:26:22 localhost catalina.sh[9228]: faultDetail:
Dec 17 02:26:22 localhost catalina.sh[9228]: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in com.sforce.soap.partner.fault.UnexpectedErrorFault - upgradeURL
```

Comment: If it is working fine, what is the issue?

Comment: Its keep on producing like if i restart the tomcat its gone but after a few while like 20 or 30 min its start coming again.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same error.

**Problem:** i was using Java 1.6 which does not have TLS 1.1 or higher support by default.

Now, there are two options to correct the situation:

1. Use JVM parameter of -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
2. Upgrade your java to 1.8 which uses TLS 1.2 (i used this one.)

Salesforce has discontinued the support TLS 1.0 from July, here is the reference: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1

Comment: I am using java 1.7 and due to some factor i cannot upgrade it to 1.8 is there any solution of this problem using java 1.7 and i tried the JVM parameter too but still the same problem.

Comment: Did you verify that parameters passing is higher than TLSv1.0 in java 1.7 ?

Comment: Yes I was passing TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 and also tried them separately.